# *ngIf of angular2 to test on three different values of the same attribute

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I'm new to angular2 , and I want to use `*ngIf` but in a little different way and it does not work. So, I have an attribute `type` within an object `item`, this type could only have **one of those three** strings :

1. type_A
2. type_B
3. unspecified

And depending on the value of `item.type` an image would be shown. I'd used it this way but seems doesnt work (images are not displayed):

```
<li *ngIf="item.type === type_A">
   <img src="assets/images/typeA-icons.png"/>
</li>
<li *ngIf="item.type === type_B">
    <img src="assets/images/typeB-icons.png"/>
</li>
<li *ngIf="item.type === unspecified">
    <img src="assets/images/unspecified-icons.png"/>
</li>
```

Any help how could I achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should wrap your strings to quotes

```
item.type === 'type_A'
```

instead of

```
item.type === type_A
```

You are looking for ngSwitch operator https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgSwitch-directive.html

```
<container-element [ngSwitch]="switch_expression">
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_1">...</some-element>
  <some-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_2">...</some-element>
  <some-other-element *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_3">...</some-other-element>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="match_expression_3">
    <!-- use a ng-container to group multiple root nodes -->
    <inner-element></inner-element>
    <inner-other-element></inner-other-element>
  </ng-container>
  <some-element *ngSwitchDefault>...</some-element>
</container-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing that with typescript:

```
public get itemImage() {
  let type = this.item && this.item.type;
  if(type === "type_A") return 'assets/images/typeA-icons.png';
  if(type === "type_B") return 'assets/images/typeB-icons.png';
  return 'assets/images/unspecified-icons.png';
}
```

HTML

```
<img [src]="itemImage" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip , it works , but cannot upvote you since i havnt enough reputations , :/ and I'd checked the other answer since it is older than yours .. sorry